# How can I add domain root to the WebLogic AdminServer classpath?

Tags: java, weblogic, classpath

How can I add the domain root path to the Oracle WebLogic 11g (10.3.2) AdminServer classpath?  (Note that I am not running the Node Manager.)  Which WebLogic startup script sets environment variable `WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH`?  Is this the variable to which I should add the domain root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set environment variable `CLASSPATH` before running `startWeblogic.sh` (Unix) or `startWeblogic.cmd` (Windows).  WebLogic Server will append this initial classpath to the end of the classpath that it generates.

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/my/domain
```